# Calculating R-squared with my own regression model in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm working on a project in R, and have run into an issue.I used the Trendline function from the basicTrendline funcion, and it did all the work for me! (YAY).

However, my hypothesis is the data would follow a trendline of y=x, but the basicTrendline function gave me y=0.96583x + 0.0029502, which is very close! However I want to be able to find it's R-squared value with respect to y=x. Does anyone know how I can go about doing this?

I'm fairly familiar with statistics, but not R, so I also don't know how to / if you can assign a function (like y=x) to a variable, but if you know how, I would also appreciate that. Thank you!

Comment: That package has [examples that include R-squared](https://github.com/PhDMeiwp/basicTrendline#case-1-default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach with `lm` from base R.

Generate some data.

```
set.seed(1) 
data <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10 + runif(-1,1,n=10))
plot(data)
abline(a=0, b=1)
```

[image]

Now fit the linear model. You can use `0 +` to fix the intercept and `offset()` to fix the `x` term. Unfortunately, `summary()` doesn't seem to work correctly, but we can calculate r.squared ourselves.

```
Model <- lm(y~0 + offset(x),data)
Residuals <- summary(Model)$residuals
SumResSquared <- sum(Residuals^2)
TotalSumSquares <- sum((data$y - mean(data$y))^2)
RSquared <- 1 - (SumResSquared/TotalSumSquares)
RSquared
#[1] 0.9582742
```

Comment: Thank you! This provided me with just what I needed. I'm still not 100% sure how the lm function works, but I've accomplished what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the R-squared of the regression from y on x you should calculate a linear model. You can do this with `model<-lm(y~x)`. WIth `summary(model)` you can find all useful details, even the R-squared.

Comment: I assume for the y and x here I substitute the values I'm considering, otherwise it would have no relation to my data. As I understand it this would create a linear model based on my data of y=ax+b, but would have values for a,b of other than, 1,0. Then my R^2 would depend on that regression model. However I do not the R^2 in relation to a linear approximation of my data, I want the R^2 in relation to the line y=x